# Dagger can't inject ViewModel's members

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2, android-viewmodel

I implemented a custom `ViewModelFactory` and Dagger DI to `ViewModel`'s members were inject by Dagger automatically, all code is below:

```
class ViewModelFactory @Inject constructor(
    private val creators: Map<Class<out ViewModel>, @JvmSuppressWildcards Provider<ViewModel>>
): ViewModelProvider.Factory {

    override fun <T : ViewModel?> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
        val creator = creators[modelClass] ?: creators.entries.firstOrNull {
            modelClass.isAssignableFrom(it.key)
        }?.value ?: throw IllegalArgumentException("unknown model class $modelClass")

        try {
            @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
            return creator.get() as T
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            throw RuntimeException(e)
        }
    }
}
```

DI:

```
@Suppress("unused")
@Module
abstract class ViewModelModule {

    @Binds
    abstract fun bindViewModelFactory(factory: ViewModelFactory): ViewModelProvider.Factory
}

@Singleton
@Component(
    modules = [
        AndroidInjectionModule::class,
        AppModule::class,
        ViewModelModule::class,
        ActivityModule::class
    ]
)
interface AppComponent: AndroidInjector<App> {

    @Component.Builder
    abstract class Builder: AndroidInjector.Builder<App>()
}

@Suppress("unused")
@Module
abstract class ActivityModule {
    @ContributesAndroidInjector(
        modules = [LoginFragmentBuilderModule::class, LoginViewModelModule::class]
    )
    abstract fun contributeLoginActivity(): LoginActivity

    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = [])
    abstract fun contributeMainActivity(): MainActivity
}

@Suppress("unused")
@Module
abstract class LoginViewModelModule {

    @Binds
    @IntoMap
    @ViewModelKey(AccountViewModel::class)
    abstract fun bindAccountViewModel(accountViewModel: AccountViewModel): ViewModel
}

@Suppress("unused")
@Module
abstract class LoginFragmentBuilderModule {

    @ContributesAndroidInjector
    abstract fun contributeAccountFragment(): AccountFragment
}

@Module
object AppModule {

    @JvmStatic
    @Provides
    fun provideGitHubApi(retrofit: Retrofit): IGitHubApi {
        return retrofit.create(IGitHubApi::class.java)
    }

    // A lot of other providers
}
```

**AccountViewModel:**:

```
class AccountViewModel(app: Application) : AndroidViewModel(app) {

    @Inject
    lateinit var gitHubApi: IGitHubApi
}
```

I wrote it using the [tutorial](https://blog.kotlin-academy.com/understanding-dagger-2-multibindings-viewmodel-8418eb372848) but I get an error on the compile time:

```
e: /test/di/AppComponent.java:8: error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] [dagger.android.AndroidInjector.inject(T)] test.ui.login.models.AccountViewModel cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or an @Provides-annotated method. This type supports members injection but cannot be implicitly provided.
public abstract interface AppComponent extends dagger.android.AndroidInjector<com.contedevel.juke.App> {
                ^
      test.ui.login.models.AccountViewModel is injected at
          test.di.LoginViewModelModule.bindAccountViewModel(accountViewModel)

      java.util.Map<java.lang.Class<? extends androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel>,javax.inject.Provider<androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel>> is injected at
          test.di.ViewModelFactory.<init>(creators)
      test.di.ViewModelFactory is injected at
          test.di.ViewModelModule.bindViewModelFactory(factory)
      androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.Factory is injected at
          test.ui.login.AccountFragment.viewModelFactory
      test.ui.login.AccountFragment is injected at
          dagger.android.AndroidInjector.inject(T)
  component path: test.di.AppComponent → test.di.ActivityModule_ContributeLoginActivity.LoginActivitySubcomponent → test.di.LoginFragmentBuilderModule_ContributeAccountFragment.AccountFragmentSubcomponent
```

Answer (score 1):

From your stack trace:

```
test.ui.login.models.AccountViewModel cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or an @Provides-annotated method
```

Your `AccountViewModel` does not have an `@Inject` constructor.

Try this:

```
class AccountViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val gitHubApi: IGitHubApi, 
    app: Application) : AndroidViewModel(app) {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly how Dagger will work in this scenario. You are binding the instance of  `AccountViewModel` through a parameter in `bindAccountViewModel`. However, now dagger will create the instance of `AccountViewModel` and it will get bind to a Map with key as `AccountViewModel::class`.

Per your stack trace, Dagger gave you suggestion that you can use constructor injection or Provide your `ViewModel` using a Provides method in a module. From our current implementation, the second suggestion becomes prevalent since we are not creating the instance of AccountViewModel. Therefore you need to pass the IGithubApi as a constructor parameter in an `AccountViewModel` that will be a viable solution in this scenario.

```
class AccountViewModel @Inject constructor(private val api: IGithubAPI, app: Application) : AndroidViewModel(app)
```